# A well-behaved subset of $\beta\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request, set-theory, compactification

Let $\beta X$ denote the usual Stone-Čech compactification of a Tychonoff space $X$. Let $S \subset \beta\mathbb{R}$ denote those points in $\beta \mathbb{R}$ which can be obtained as a **limit point** of a sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}$ (since there are $2^c$-many points in $\beta\mathbb{R}$, $S$ seems small in size in $\beta\mathbb{R}$ in a certain sense).

My question is, is $S$ open in $\beta\mathbb{R}$? Seems a bit counter-intuitive, but I cannot prove or disprove this. Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: In the first version of this question, I mistakenly asked about points which can be obtained as the **limit** of a sequence of real numbers, and as has been pointed out below, in that case $S = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Every point of $\beta X\setminus X$ is not a limit of sequences over $X$, if $X$ is normal. Hence your $S$ is just $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @HanulJeon I somehow really doubt this, how about the sequence  $\{ n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$? This is a sequence in $\beta\mathbb{R}$, which is compact.

Comment: The sequence may have a limit point. The point is it does not have a unique limit.

Comment: @user346998 That the space is compact doesn't imply that every sequence has a convergent subsequence. This only works in metric spaces.

Comment: @HanulJeon If a sequence has a limit, then its limit is unique by Hausdorffness of $\beta\mathbb R$, isn't it?

Comment: @Wojowu Right. But I have intended a set of accumulation points of a set given by a sequence.

Comment: @HanulJeon I was clumsy in asking the question, I have edited it now. Thanks for your input though, and I would be highly grateful if you could take a look at the edited question.

Comment: To answer an edited question: set of all limit points of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\beta\mathbb{R}$. The word *compactification* requires that the closure of the original space is that compatification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $S$ is all of $\beta\mathbb{R}$.  Indeed, let $(x_n)$ be any enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$.  Then $\{x_n\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and hence also dense in $\beta\mathbb{R}$.  So every point of $\beta\mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of the sequence $(x_n)$.

---

*The following addresses the original version of the question, where $S$ was the set of limits of sequences in $\mathbb{R}$.*

Suppose $x\in S\setminus\mathbb{R}$ and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of distinct points in $\mathbb{R}$ converging to $x$.  Then there is a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x_n)=0$ if $n$ is odd and $f(x_n)=1$ if $n$ is even (since $\{x_n\}$ is a discrete closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$).  This $f$ cannot be continuously extended to $x$, which is a contradiction.

Thus $S=\mathbb{R}$.  Since $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact, it is open in $\beta\mathbb{R}$, so $S$ is open.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken when asking the question, I wanted to say **limit points** instead. But thanks for your answer, it is quite illuminating. May be you would be kind enough to overlook my mistake and shed some light on the edited question?

Comment: I've edited the answer to address that.

Comment: If $X$ is normal and $Y$ is a closed subset of $X$ then $ id_Y:Y\to Cl_{\beta X}(Y)$ is the maximal compactification of $Y.$.....  So if $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R$ with no limit point in $\mathbb R$ then the set  $Y=\{x_n\}_n$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ and is homeomorphic to the discrete space $\mathbb N.$ So $Cl_{\beta \mathbb R}(Y)$ is homeomorphic to $\beta \mathbb N ,$ which is (very) uncountable .

Comment: @user254665 One curiosity: if one defined $S$ to consist of all points which are in the closure of a **discrete set** in $\mathbb{R}$, can we say anything about whether $S$ is open then?

Comment: @EricWofsey This answers my question, thanks! One curiosity: if one defined $S$ to consist of all points which are in the closure of a **discrete set** in $\mathbb{R}$, can we say anything about whether $S$ is open then?

Comment: Regarding your last comment, if $S$ is both open and closed in $\beta R$ then so is its complement $S^c$ in $\beta R$. But then $S\cap R$ and $S^c\cap R$ are disjoint open subsets of $R$ whose union is $R$, so one of them is empty. So if $S$ is not empty it is $R$.  But then $S$ cannot be  the closure in $R$ of a discrete set $T$ because   $ int_R(R $ \ $T)$ is not empty and is disjoint from $Cl_R(T)=S.$

Comment: @user346998: I believe in that case the complement of $S$ is actually dense in $\beta\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{R}$.  As a sketch of the argument, if $U$ is any neighborhood of a point of $\beta\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, it contains an unbounded union of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.  We may assume the total measure of these intervals is infinite.  Now take all the subsets of this union of intervals whose complements have finite measure.  These have the finite intersection property, so their closures in $\beta\mathbb{R}$ have nonempty intersection.

Comment: An intersection point is then not in $S$, since given a discrete set you can find a neighborhood of it with finite measure.  So this gives a point in the closure of $U$ which is not in $S$.  So every closed neighborhood of a point of $\beta\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ contains a point not in $S$, so the complement of $S$ is dense in $\beta\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{R}$.  Since the complement is not all of $\beta\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, it is not closed, so $S$ is not open.